# Closed sets in metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I have just proven any closed set in the plane (R^2) with the usual metric is the boundary of some subset of the plane.

I am now struggling to find a counterexample to show that this is not true for any metric space.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Actually it is true.

Comment: Oops sorry, I commented too quickly. My mistake !

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use the standard source of counterexamples: a discrete metric space.

Comment: Okay got it thanks!

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the space $E = \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace$, endowed with the induced metric.

The subset $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is closed, but is not the boundary of any subset.